# PHP: Mongodb connection to server using IP

Tags: php, mongodb, database-connection, ip

I am trying to connect to a mongodb server in my php file which is on my local. The mongodb server is on another server whose IP i know. There is no username and password set on the server for the mongodb. I have installed the php driver for mongodb too as required on my system.

Mongodb is working fine on the server. I have checked that.

When i run my php script its giving **error**: 
*The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/test/mongo_test.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.*

Is there anything else i need to configure ? If yes where? and also how?

Comment: what is the code in mongo_test.php ?

Comment: Hi @srijan, show us the code you're running.

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using to connect to MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The server most likely has a firewall in place not allowing outside access to the particular port MongoDB is running on for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

We had to set *bind_ip: 0.0.0.0* in the config file.

Read more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#file-format

"To bind to all IPv4 addresses, you can specify the bind ip address of 0.0.0.0. To bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, you can specify the bind ip address of ::,0.0.0.0 or alternatively, use the new net.bindIpAll setting or the new command-line option --bind_ip_all."

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-mongodb-configuration/